# Is there any public documentation saying Facebook test users don't work with iOS 6 integration?

Tags: ios, facebook, integration

Facebook test users aren't supposed to be able to friend real people, and there are other major restrictions.

They're created by tying them to an original app, although they can later be associated with other apps.

This is info I remember reading the last time I created test facebook users.

They WORK with Single-sign-on, but after upgrading to "Facebook SDK for iOS 3.x" for the supported iOS integration, I've found these test users do not work with iOS 6 Facebook integration, neither in simulator, nor on device.

Could anyone confirm this with documentation?  It's a little hard to search for given the amount of terms and I've already been searching for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting a Facebook bug report, it was marked as duplicate of an active, high-priority issue.

**iOS6 Facebook integration does not work with test users**

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/452331201480283

**Edit (August 17 2013)**

I just noticed this Facebook bug was marked as Fixed on the 12th of this month.  A quick test confirms it is fixed, for me at least.

Comment: To be fair, the [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/452331201480283) has been open since November 27th 2012

Comment: Yet no one brought it up on SO when I asked. :) But it's all good.